# Which protocol should be used to send video stream to a media server for live streaming?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rtsp, live-streaming

I am working on an iOS application to stream live video from iPhone to  a media server and then make it available to a larger audience using RTSP.

Which protocol or method I should use to send the video stream to a server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Live streaming is not designed for you needs, it's for server->clients + I won't comment about huge delay it implies

You better check RTSP or RTMP protocol and LivU blog

Comment: I had thought of using RTSP but I found a question on StackOverflow where another person's App was rejected by Apple for not using HLS in his App. I asked a question related to it at this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917814/can-rtsp-real-time-streaming-protocol-be-used-to-send-live-video-stream-from-i
Do you have anyy idea about it?

Comment: I wireshark'd a lot of streaming app on the app store, none of them use HLS

Answer (score 0):

For Celluar
Apple seems to make a distinction between apps that are used for just streaming content from servers and those that are used for some type of conferencing.
I think VOIP types are safe, and it seems like gocoder presenter types apps don't have issues either. There's no official page detailing this, but there is some mention under what apples considers VOIP app.

No app has issues if its over wifi only.