# Can RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol) be used to send live video stream from iPhone to a media server?

Tags: iphone, ios, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I am new to iOS and multimedia development and I am working on an application which will capture video from iPhone's camera and send the live stream to a media server.

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719958/how-to-use-http-live-streaming-protocol-in-iphone-sdk-3-0) a person asked a question on *stackoverflow* saying that his application was rejected by Apple as he didn't use `Apple HLS` (HTTP Live Streaming) method in his application for receiving the live stream.

But my case is different as I am not receiving a live stream in the iPhone.

I have to send the live video to a media server without saving it in the phone's memory which will be later watched by people on their computers through internet.
So is it okay if I use `RTSP` to send the live video stream to a server or is it compulsory in my case as well to use `Apple HLS`?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using only Wi-Fi (not cellular network), then you can use any protocols.

Answer (score 1):

It's yes, you can definitely use RSTP to to send video stream from your ios app to a server as long as you do not stream it back to ios app using RSTP. Apple official documentation states that:

**"if your app delivers video over cellular networks, and the video exceeds either 10 minutes duration or 5 MB of data in a five minute period, you are required to use HTTP Live Streaming."**

So, it is not talking anything about what protocol you should use when you are sending video to the server.

Comment: Could you link to the apple docs?

Answer (score 0):

Our interpretation is that if the app is a voip app, like conferencing it gets special consideration otherwise you must use hls if not on wifi.

Comment: You can use rtsp over wifi or cell in a voip app.

Answer (score 0):

We have published an app sending real-time video from iPhone from server and it does not use HLS. There are dozens of other apps in app store using proprietary protocols as well. So the answer is no, it is not required to use HLS when streaming video from iPhone.

Comment: You mean sending live stream video from **iPhone to server**.. Rite?